# Installation of IBM ILOG cplex12.10 on VirtualBox

Tags: virtualbox, ubuntu-gnome, ibm

I am trying to install the Free Academic version of the software ILOG CPLEX Optimization Studio v12.10 on Ubuntu 20.10.

When I execute the file I get

```
Preparing to install
WARNING: /tmp does not have enough disk space! Attempting to use /home/lauva for install base and tmp dir.

WARNING! The amount of /home/lauva disk space required to perform this installation is greater than 
what is available. Please free up at least 1760088 kilobytes in /home/lauva and attempt this installation again.
```

I have looked for solutions and I was attempting at  increasing the size of this partition just to do the upgrade by following these instructions:

```
sudo umount /tmp
sudo mount -t tmpfs -o size=1048576,mode=1777 overflow /tmp
```

But then I get again the same mistake.

Has anyone experienced this kind of problem? Is it fixable?

Comment: I just did this last night. Close the VM. Open VirtualBox and, under global tools, make the drive bigger (make the .vdi larger, it's a handy slider in the version I'm using). Reboot the VM to a *live USB of your favorite Linux distro*, and use GParted to increase the size of your VM's partition. When you're done, just unmount the live ISO and reboot the VM. It's just like doing it on physical hardware.

Comment: Thank you @KGIII

Comment: No problem. I'm sure it's on the site somewhere as an answer and it's rather straightforward, so I don't feel it needs a full answer. I can write one, if you really want.